# scala pattern matching with variable in case clause

Tags: scala, design-patterns, matching

I want to do a pattern matching with scala but I have the problem that I want to know if the object is the same type as a variable.

I have this:

```
user.role match {
  case this.role.getClass => true //here says stable identifier required, but this.role.getClass found
  case _: Role_Admin => true
  case _ => false
}
```

I understand the problem here, but I need to match it with the variable stored in the instance. Is there any way to do that? Or does anyone know any other good way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Let me ask you this: How is "role" implemented? Does it have a finite number of possible values? (You most likely want to define a `Role` ADT, here.)

Comment: What's `role`? What's `this`?

Comment: Thank you  for the answers. This is the object where I have to verify the user's role, and role is the role that the user needs to access the link.  Role is an abstract class and there are 2 case classes implementing it (for now, there will be one or two more I think)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using guards: assign the result to a variable and check any `Boolean` condition.

```
user.role match {
  case role if role.getClass == this.role.getClass => true
  case _: Role_Admin => true
  case _ => false
}
```

but I'd be quite suspicious of a design which needs this.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. What I need is to verify the user's role in order to know if it can access the page. The roles are case classes to use pattern matching here.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the object where I have to verify the user's role

Usage of `this.role` implies that this check happens inside a method of `User`(`this` is of type `User`, because it has a `role`). `user.role match` implies that you have another user.

I don't know your intention for that, but given `Role` defined like this:

```
trait Role {}
case object Admin extends Role
case object Guest extends Role
```

you can have `User` and that method like this:

```
case class User(role: Role) {
  def hasAccess(user: User): Boolean = 
    user.role match {
      case this.role => true
      case Admin => true
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

If you're still talking about checking permission in a different object, than using `this` there doesn't make any sense. You just need to pass a `User` to a method and check only that user:

```
object PermissionChecker {
  def hasAccess(user: User): Boolean = user.role match {
    case Admin => true
    case Guest => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

*NOTE:* In your case it seems that it's easier to use trait and case objects to model `Role`'s. But if you write that you have `Role` as an abstract class, and actual roles as case classes:

```
abstract class Role {}
case class Admin() extends Role
case class Guest() extends Role
```

than the idea stays the same, but you have to adjust the syntax a bit:

```
case class User(role: Role) {
  def hasAccess(user: User): Boolean = user.role match {
    case this.role => true
    case _: Admin => true
    case _ => false
   }
}
```

Variant with a separate object:

```
object PermissionChecker {
  def hasAccess(user: User): Boolean = user.role match {
    case _: Admin => true
    case _: Guest => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer! I tried using case objects because I think that it's better for what I want to do. My problem with that is that I'm persisting my model with hibernate and I could't persist the objects. Do you know if there is any way to do that? Thank you!